# PHP Convert date format

Tags: javascript, php

I have the  following date format in PHP : 06/22/2015 12:28 PM how can I convert it to this format : 06-22-2015 12:28 PM in PHP or Javascript ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php

Comment: $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i A','06/22/2015 12:28 PM');

echo $dateObj->format('m-d-Y H:i A');

Answer (score 1):

Try using simple [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function

```
$date = '06/22/2015 12:28 PM';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i a',$date);
echo $date->format('m-d-Y H:i a');//06-22-2015 12:28 pm
```